# Use name doesn’t render in all browsers?

Tags: discussion

Evidently it’s possible to use characters or formatting codes in use names that don’t work on all platforms/browsers.

[image: your name is P]

Comment: Odd. I've had this name for quite a while now and no one else has said anything. Anyone else seeing problems? Or if interest, what OS and language variant are you using?

Comment: I've seen that too -- I see "PETE" in chat on my desktop computer but "P E " on my phone.  I assume @Pᴇᴛᴇ is using some special Unicode characters or something (like the OP :-) ).

Comment: Odd again. In my iPhone, it renders just fine. I'm happy enough to change to the more boring normal version though

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ it *would* make searching based on your name a lot easier.

Comment: Who in their right mind would want to search for me???

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ I tried to it today, when you made your 10k comment in chat to see how far away you were. But I couldn't find your name, so no upvotes :)

Comment: Haha... I'll have to figure out how to change my name then!

Comment: Platform: See [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119252/missing-glyphs-on-web-pages).  Mention it? People just think your name is P and [don’t not ice](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Kerning).

Comment: You can change it on your Profile page.  Tres-2b does so frequently.

Comment: Maybe someone can report just what Unicode characters are being used (by number).  P doesn't know since he just copied it from someone else (and now he knows the hazards of copying strange glyphs).

Comment: It this better now?

Comment: @Pete if it’s supposed to read “Pete”.  I still wonder what it said before…

Comment: @JDługosz it was Pete in small caps

Comment: Interesting. There was only a gap suggesting 1 invisible character.  Unicode doesn’t have “small caps”, so it was probably a hack of finding characters that just happen to look like smaller letters.